How to create a list of dict without null values in Ansible?
I want to create a list of dictionaries of files and their corresponding checksums based on the variables defined. The list should not contain files and checksums that are not defined.
How do I do this?
vars_file.yaml
file_a: a.txt
file_b: b.txt
file_c: 
file_a_checksum: 12345656
file_b_checksum: 12345676
file_c_checksum:

I want the final list to contain
[{ 'name': a.txt, 'checksum': 12345656 }, { 'name': b.txt, 'checksum': 12345676 }]

I tried using the following condition in set_fact
when: file_c is defined and file_c | length > 0

but this still adds file_c as null to the list.

Please [edit] your question such that your question contains a [mre], and provide more details and what you tried. See [ask] for reference.

How are you making a list out of it in the first place?
